# Unix errors running C++ program involving struct tm

Tags: c++, unix, visual-studio-2012, fstream

I wrote an Inventory program for groceries in C++ using Visual Studio 2012 and
everything runs smoothly and as expected. A file is read in as a command line argument and that is used to fill a deque with Grocery objects. A function that I used to check if a Grocery object was expiring soon used time_t and struct tm. When trying to run my program on Unix, I get an **error involving fstream**

**Here are the lines of code where I am getting the errors:**

```
    int main (int argc, char** argv) {

    deque<Grocery> groceries;
    deque<Grocery>::iterator iter;
    string filename = "";

    if (argc > 1) {
        filename = argv[1];
        fstream fileData;
        fileData.open(filename, ios::in | ios::out); //**error**
        //error check
        if (!fileData) {
            cout << "Error openeing file. Program aborting.\n";
            return 1;
        }
        string name;
        string expDate;
        string type;
        string quantity;

        while (!fileData.eof()) {
            Grocery temp;
            getline (fileData,name,'\t');
            temp.setName(name);
            getline (fileData,expDate,'\t');
            temp.setExpDate(expDate);
            getline (fileData,type,'\t');
            temp.setType(type);
            getline (fileData, quantity,'\n');
            temp.setQuantity(atoi (quantity.c_str()));
            groceries.push_back(temp);
        }   
        fileData.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Errors when trying to run program in Unix**

```
  $ make all
g++ -c Grocery.cpp
g++ -c Inventory.cpp
Inventory.cpp: In function âint main(int, char**)â:
Inventory.cpp:24:45: error: no matching function for call to âstd::basic_fstream<char>::open(std::string&, std::_Ios_Openmode)â
   fileData.open(filename, ios::in | ios::out);
                                             ^
Inventory.cpp:24:45: note: candidate is:
In file included from Inventory.cpp:3:0:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/include/c++/4.8.1/fstream:886:7: note: void std::basic_fstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
       open(const char* __s,
       ^
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/include/c++/4.8.1/fstream:886:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from âstd::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}â to âconst char*â
make: *** [Inventory.o] Error 1
```

**Makefile**

```
MKFILE    = Makefile

#
# Definitions of list of files:
#
HSOURCES  = Grocery.h
CSOURCES  = Grocery.cpp Inventory.cpp

ETCSRC    = README ${MKFILE}
EXECBIN   = main
ALLCSRC   = ${CSOURCES}
OBJECTS   = ${ALLCSRC:.cpp=.o}
ALLSRC    = ${ETCSRC} ${HSOURCES} ${CSOURCES}
LISTSRC   = ${ALLSRC}

#
# Definitions of the compiler and compilation options:
#
GCC       = g++

#
# The first target is always ``all'', and hence the default,
# and builds the executable images
#
all : ${EXECBIN}

#
# Build the executable image from the object files.
#
${EXECBIN} : ${OBJECTS}
        ${GCC} -o ${EXECBIN} ${OBJECTS}

#
# Build an object file form a C source file.
#
%.o : %.cpp
        ${GCC} -c $<

#
# Clean and spotless remove generated files.
#
clean :
        - rm -rf ${EXECBIN} ${OBJECTS}
```

**FIXED** 
Answer listed below

Comment: what is the datatype of `expDate`

Comment: Sorry bout that. Here are the variables that are initialized in my Grocery.h file:
time_t t;
struct tm *expDate;

Comment: Wait. `expDate` is a `struct tm *` ? [Check the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime), because `localtime()` returns a pointer to an internal object that is subject to overwrite on a number of different conditions, including another call to `localtime()`. I.e. you can't just save that pointer and expect it to be valid forever.

Comment: And as-written if `expDate` is indeed `struct tm *expDate;`, that line won't fail to compile, assuming you've included `<ctime>`. So either that isn't how it is declared or that isn't the line where the error is. *Post complete code*.

Comment: WhozCraig, Thanks for the response. I have this code working as intended when running through Visual Studio, but am getting these errors when trying to run through Unix. Any idea why that's happening?

Comment: The code looks OK. Post a complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Updated Code. Errors occur when compiling in Unix with provided Makefile

Comment: See http://ideone.com/GDoNKd for an example code. You want to reduce your code to something similar in size.

Comment: n.m. My code is identical to the example code you provided, but rather my tm* and time_t variables are data members to my Grocery class. This couldn't be the problem, could it?

Comment: You have `string expDate` that may be messing things up. Your code is not identical. Identical code produces identical results.

Comment: There's a typo in `Grocery.h`; you test for `#ifndef GROCERY_H` but set `#define GROCER_H`.  This only breaks when I ran a test for idempotence on the header.  Otherwise, I copied `Grocery.h` and `Grocery.cpp` from the question to my Mac and compiled with `g++` 4.8.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.2 and it compiled to object code without problems.

Comment: Jonathan! Thank you! That took care of the struct tm* errors, but now I'm getting one in my Inventory.cpp file involving my fstream. I edited the post above to reflect the new error, if you could take a look at it, I would be so grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Inventory.cpp:24:45: error: no matching function for call to âstd::basic_fstream<char>::open(std::string&, std::_Ios_Openmode)â
fileData.open(filename, ios::in | ios::out);
```

[`basic_fstream(const string&, ios_base::openmode)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream) constructor is only available in C++11 mode.

You are compiling your code in C++98 mode. Pass `-std=gnu++11` to `g++` when compiling.

Comment: Thank you Maxim! That did the trick. Is there any way I can get out of C++98 mode permanentaly? I'm still fairly new to Unix.

Comment: @KyleN C++98 is the default mode for gcc-4.8.2. You need to pass `-std=gnu++11` explicitly to switch it. You can normally change your compiler flags by editing your makefile.

Comment: @KyleN The default of C++98 for `g++` will probably never change because that would break existing applications that expect to be compiled in C++98 and do not pass any `-std=` option to the compiler.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and informative replies. I'll be editing this post a bit to address this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a clean build.
Since you have the declarations in header file, and you might have changed the expDate from type tm to tm*.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I don't know how to extract the current time without using localtime. Would you mind showing me what how you would implement that with memcpy?

Comment: sorry, leave memcpy thing apart. Just have edited the post. It is clear that expDate is recognized as tm structure and not a pointer by the compiler. So try looking into it.